# AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Getting below error while uploading image through paperclip in ROR.

> AWS::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied

Below is the s3 settings:

```
:default_url => "/assets/:style/dummy.png",
:storage => :s3,
:s3_credentials => "s3.yml",
:path => "/user/:id/:style/:filename",
:url => ":s3_domain_url",
:s3_region => 'us-east-1'
```

`s3.yml` setting:

```
development:
bucket: my_bucket_name
access_key_id: 'access_key'
secret_access_key: 'secret_key'
```

any workaround for this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is due to the permissions you have on the files stored in the bucket. If you log into the [Amazon S3 management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com) you can find the directory or file and grant permissions to everyone for open/download. Assuming that's what you want for the dummy.png

Comment: thanks for reply...i already set all permissions to everyone.